# Trying to Log into vrv using requests, but results usually come in semi blank

Tags: python, parsing, python-requests

im just trying to log into vrv and get the list of shows from the crunchyroll page so i can just open the site later, but when i try to get back the parsed website after logging in. Theres a lot of info missing like titles and images and its incomplete. This is the code i have up to now. Obviously my email and password isnt email and password, i just changed them to post it here.

```
import requests
import pyperclip as p


def enterVrv():
     s = requests.Session()

     dataL = {'email': 'email', 'password': 'password'}

     s.post('https://static.vrv.co/vrvweb/build/common.6fb25c4cff650ac4e6ae.js', data=dataL)

     crunchy = s.get('https://vrv.co/crunchyroll/browse')

     p.copy(str(crunchy.content))
     exit(0)
```

Ive tried posting from the normal 'https://vrv.co' site, i tried from the 'https://vrv.co.signin' link, and i tried the link you currently see in the code that i got from the networks pane in the developers tool. After i ran the code i would take the copied html and replace the current one on a webbrowser to see if its pulling up correctly, but it all comes in incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that you're trying to get data from a **web page** that's being loaded *dynamically*. Indeed, if you navigate to `https://vrv.co/crunchyroll/browse` in your browser you'll likely notice there's a delay in between the page loading and the cruncyroll titles being displayed.

It also looks like `vrv` does not expose an API for you to programmatically access this data either.

To get around this you could try accessing the page via a web automation tool such as selenium and scraping the data that way. As for just making a basic request to the site though, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: dang, thats unfortunate thanks though. So how do i tell if a page is being loaded dynamically or not to save me time lmao? Is the delay of the titles loading a flag that details this?

Comment: Yea, that's a pretty good indication that a site's being loaded dynamically. Unfortunately again, there's not really a definitive way to tell that I know of.